# logger in custom module of widfly is not working

Tags: module, log4j, wildfly

I am working on web application project in wildfly. I have a web-application project which has dependency on authentication jar file. Instead of placing the authentication jar file in WEB-INF/lib, the authentication jar file placed in wildfly custom module says "com.example.authentication"

The authentication project does have log4j propery file for the logger, however, log4j jar file has been invoked common module says "com.example.logger" having log4j.jar file.

I expect the logger to be working in authentication project but the logger is not working for authentication module. NO errors or warnings on this.

- Webapplication - WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

  ```
  <jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
     <module name="com.example.authentication"/>
   </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
  ```
- com.example.authentication - module.xml

  ```
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1:3" name="com.example.authentication">
       <resources>
      <resource-root path="authentication.jar"
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="com.example.logger" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
     </module>
  ```

  - com.example.logger - module.xml

Comment: Are you saying that the module `com.example.authentication` is not logging anything?

Comment: That's correct. I would expect the module to log but it's not.

Comment: Can you add the `module.xml` for the `com.example.logger` module as well as just a listing of it's contents?

Comment: Sure. Here is the one .. **bold**<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1:3" name="com.example.logger"><resources>
    <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.4.jar"/><resource-root path="log4j.1.2.12.jar"/>
  </resources></module>**bold**

Comment: Instead of adding a log4j resource try depending on the `org.apache.log4j` dependency.